# Possible jruby dependency issue

Tags: rubygems, rvm, jruby

I built JRuby from source and got the jirb working. When I went to install a gem I waited ~30 seconds and then the process ended like this:

```
$ jruby -S gem install jekyll
Killed
```

I tried a couple other gems with the same result. Then I removed the JRuby build and files from my system and installed it again with RVM.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=jruby
```

I'm still getting the same issue. I've had a hard time finding help for this online. There's nothing I could find on the JRuby site and the RVM installer is supposed to "just work". Am I missing any dependencies? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

when I tried it I got the following

```
Fetching: fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/g/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

 (root) at /Users/g/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
 (root) at /Users/g/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
 (root) at extconf.rb:1
```

looks like fast-stemmer has [c code](https://github.com/romanbsd/fast-stemmer/blob/master/ext/porter.c) which jruby doesn't support